# Random performance of AspectJ

Tags: java, aspectj

I just started learning AspectJ with simple code. 
here is my Main class:

```
public class Main {

    public void say() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Main m = new Main();
       m.say();

    }
}
```

and my aspect is:

```
public aspect Demo {

    pointcut test():call(* Main.say());
    before():test() {
        System.out.println("ASPECT");
    }
}
```

However, it only shows "hello" without "ASPECT". When I put another static method in Main class, the "ASPECT" appears sometime.
BTW, I am using Intellij Idea and having no clue why it is not working properly.

Comment: This is likely a problem with IntelliJ, so you would need to add information about your IntelliJ version and how you set up this project (pom.xml, gradle).

Comment: Close to impossible to answer without knowing your build environment. Probably best if you just create a pure maven build and start it from command line to see if that works.